# How to display the contents of a file using PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html, file

So this is what I have so far on the PHP side

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $file = fopen("names.txt", "a+");
    fwrite($file,$name);
    fclose($file);

    $readFile = fopen("names.txt", "r");
    fread($file);
}
?>
```

How would I display on my webpage what has been read from the file?

Comment: You should `echo $yourfile;`

Answer (score 0):

You can do `echo $yourfile` simpler way!

You should also use [readfile()](http://php.net/readfile):

```
readfile("/path/to/file");
```

This will read the file and send it to the browser in one command.This is same as.

```
echo file_get_contents("/path/to/file");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use file_get_contents()

```
$file = file_get_contents('names.txt', true);
echo $file;
```